# HTML/javascript online experiment - video speed varying across browsers (too fast in safari, OK in chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, safari, mechanicalturk

I am writing my first HTML/javascript/jquery page to present online using mechanical turk. The experiment entails a set of trials, each of which is a video showing a rapid stream of images with blank screen between images. We are using videos instead of the images themselves because we already had a matlab script from in-lab experiments to do the counterbalancing of images within a trial and across trials. I would like to keep using the videos if possible, but I have no idea how to resolve this issue I'm having with playback speed --

Everything seems to be working fine in Chrome, and the videos present at normal speed. However, when I go to test it in Safari, everything basically works the same as Chrome EXCEPT that the video speed is somehow too fast, and I have NO idea why. It is not *absurdly* fast, but > 1x for sure. (I don't know how to figure out how much faster exactly). I have a keypress trigger to start the trial video now (which fixed a different issue but not this one), and I've tried all different values for the preload attribute on the video tag. My videos are mp4.Everything is hosted on my local machine for now.

does anyone have any idea why playback speed would differ across browsers? It is very important that the timing is accurate and consistent for all subjects, so this is very important to resolve. Is this even an issue with my code (e.g. is there an attribute I should have or certain way to load?), or an issue with my computer (Mac, running Catalina 10.15.1) , or an issue with my browser (safari ver. is 13.0.3)?

Please help me figure out what is going on!

***EDIT: here is an actual "minimal reproducible example"*** I deleted all the nonsense I had above, thank you to first 2 commenters who helped me set this up more appropriately --
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f21trckjf1hte9g/AAB4T4XMDJDydhlINhsnp_YIa?dl=0

(the issue still does occur w/ just the script here (and there is just one video for a demo present in the folder)

Comment: I made you a snippet. If you click edit, then scroll down to click "edit above snippet" you can see code highlighting showing invalid attributes and possibly more

Comment: We do expect a [mcve] and some explanation of input and expeted output. Right now the snippet does nothing as far as I can see

Comment: ok sorry, would it be ok to share a dropbox link to the whole project? I will add one to the bottom of my post, I think it would be difficult to properly reproduce the environment otherwise

Comment: Your video file says it has a FrameRate of 1000FPS! 17210 kb/s! Reencode it using safer values like 120FPS if you really want it precise, or even smaller, anyway most monitors are limited to 60Hz, but at 1000FPS no surprises browsers' decoders can't cope with it ;-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by an issue not related to programing.

Comment: ahh!!!! thank you @Kaiido -- perfect, and yes I will close this. Thank you for giving an answer anyway!